# Extract Data from the struct in Swift

Tags: swift

I have made a struct in which I'm passing my data. The data is in an array. I'm running a `for` loop to get the value out from it but I'm not getting full values. Suppose there is `5.0` value in an array when the loop runs. It first shows me `5`, then `.`, and then `0`. I want it to give `5.0` to me rather than seperate values.

My loop is this:

```
for price in ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price! {
    print(price)
}
```

It shows this in console:

[image]

This is my class for Items:

```
class Item : NSObject {
    var name : String?
    var price : String?
    var  itemDdescription : String?
}

class ItemDataSource : NSObject {
    var items = [Item]()
    static let sharedInstance = ItemDataSource()
    private override init() {}
}
```

Here I'm passing my values to it:

```
let item = Item()
item.name = itemName
item.price = String(result)
item.itemDdescription = String(describing: description)
ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items.append(item)
```

Comment: show contents of `temDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!`

Comment: i have edited my question check it. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: I meant to print what is stored in `ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!`

Comment: yeah i want the value what is in it but one by one , the values can be more than one. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: print it and copy paste it here.. I want to see how it looks

Comment: it is showing 5.0 but i'm trying to get the sum of the values coming in this array. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: can you just print it and copy paste it here please?

Comment: it shows this 5.0 in console. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: OK, I get it now.. check the answers, and continue from there

Comment: You're not asking a Swift question. You're asking an atoi() question with sum. Google how to get sums of strings in swift, or similar. Also atoi() is the original C function (alphanumeric to integer). atof() parse int, other keywords you may want to try

Answer (score 1):

Explanation:

`ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!` is a `String`, iterating over it means to iterate over the characters that are in it. So if the `ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!" is "5.0", it will print "5", "." and then "0".

To get the price for the given row, just use

```
let price = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!
```

as @John Ottenlips suggested.

Comment: How can i get the sum of the price coming in it? if we have more than one value ? @ Milan Nosáľ

Comment: @Hamza there is one price coming in it.. can you show an example of multiple prices? "5.0" is a single price.. and as john mentioned, if there are more prices, it's better to store it as an array instead of coding it into a single string

Comment: i have to append it to an array? and then sum it? @Milan Nosáľ

Comment: @Hamza there is only 1 price.. why are you talking about multiple prices?

Comment: Bro, in my situation price can be more than 1 it depends on user how much he can add. @ Milan Nosáľ

Comment: Bro i can explain u the scenario can i come on a discussion with me? @ Milan Nosáľ

Comment: @Hamza sure, but you have not shown how that situation looks.. where are the other prices? how are they coded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166060/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-hamza).

Answer (score 0):

Your loop may be unnecessary. indexPath.row will increase and allow you to iterate through your items in this delegate method. If you are just trying to get one price per cell try

`let price = ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[indexPath.row].price!`

`print(price)`

A general code smell is having a for loop inside a method you are returning a cell in.

Comment: The values in it might be more than one. i want to get value out of it. @John Ottenlips

Comment: I would suggest using an array of prices instead of a string of prices if you have more than one price.

Comment: Bro i want to add the values coming in this , suppose if there are two values 5 and 7 it should give me 12. @John Ottenlips

Comment: :) That is a different question